# JavaFx RichText based on HTML

Tags: java, javafx

I wish to display a history of messages inside ListView.

Example message:

```
Hello World. <b>Hello world</b>. <u><font color="#FF0000">Hello World</font></u>.
```

And example ListView

```
+---ListView----+
| first message |
+---------------+
| second very   |
| long message  |
+---------------+
| third message |
+---------------+
```

Each message could be represented by a simple label. But:

- it has to wrap the text
- it has to parse simple html tags and format text

How can I achieve that with javafx components?

Comment: Use a `cellFactory` on the `ListView` that creates cells that use a `WebView`.

Comment: Displaying ~100 instances of WebView is not an overkill?